# Applying strstr() multiple times on same string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strstr, strstream

I'm trying to write a code that extracts all words/strings between the  and  tags using strstr. But it seems that it just gets stuck to the first string extracted, which is "quick". How can I get the code to keep going after extracting the first string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char feed[] = "The <item> quick </item> brown <item> fox </item> jumps <item> over </item> the <item> lazy dog </item>";


    const char needle[] = "<item>";
    const char popo[] = "</item>";
    char *ret;
    char *ter;
    int n;
    n = 0;

    while (feed[n] != '\0')
    {
        ret = strstr(feed, needle)+6;
        ter = strstr(ret, popo);
        size_t len = ter - ret;
        char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
        strncpy(res, ret, len);
        res[len] = '\0';

        printf("%s",res);
        n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heavy on the return key - Not so heavy on the spacebar - indent the code!

Comment: [Do not cast `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495). This, `ret = strstr(feed, needle)+6;` is dangerous, if `strstr()` reutrns `NULL` you end up with `(void *)0x06` instead of `(void *)0x00` and dereferencing that is a problem. Also, use `memcpy()` instead of `strncpy()` like `memcpy(res, ret, len)` and check that `res != NULL` before doing that.

Comment: If I remove the +6, the output will include the string "<item>".

Comment: You can add the length of `<item>` after you check `ret != NULL`, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `ret` pointer to point to the current position in the string, and increment it by length on each iteration, and pass `ret` to the first `strstr()` instead of `feed`, check out this implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char       feed[]   = "The <item> quick </item> brown <item> fox </item> "
                          "jumps <item> over </item> the <item> lazy dog </item>";
    const char needle[] = "<item>";
    const char popo[]   = "</item>";
    char      *head;
    int n;
    n = 0;

    head = feed;
    while (feed[n] != '\0')
    {
        char  *tail;
        char  *copy;
        size_t length;

        head = strstr(head, needle);
        /*            ^ always start at the current position. */
        if (head == NULL)
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input...???\n");
            return -1;
         }
        tail   = strstr(head, popo);
        length = tail - head - 6;
        head  += 6;
        if (length < 0)
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input...???\n");
            return -1;
         }
        copy = malloc(length + 1);
        if (copy != NULL)
         {
            memcpy(copy, head, length);
            copy[length] = '\0';

            printf("*%s*\n", copy);
            /* If you are not going to keep it, free it */
            free(copy);
         }
        head += length; /* <-- this is the imprtant thing */
        n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask, which variable and in which part does the program extract the first word and get the result? I want to put each string in an array for use later on in the code

Comment: you can do that in the `/* If you are not going to keep it, free it */` by not freeing the pointer and storing it somewhere.

Comment: When I do
    memcpy(meti[a].item, copy, length);
after the 
    copy[length] ='\0';

It only copies the last result of the program, or in other words, the last string enclosed in the last <item> </item> tags. Why does it go directly to the last? I need to copy each string extracted, starting from the first to the last, in an array to printf them later on. Please help

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
ret = strstr(feed, needle)+6;
```

You are always starting your search from the beginning of the `feed` string.  You need to pass a different starting point to `strstr`, which you already have in `ter`.  So you should be able to do something like this:

```
ter = feed;
while (ter != NULL) 
{
     ret = strstr(ter, needle) + 6;
...
```

With this the start of your search will keep moving farther down the `feed` string.

There are some other issues in your code:

1. `strstr()` can return NULL if it doesn't find a match - you need to check for that or you program will crash.
2. You need to `free()` the memory you `malloc()`
3. As @iharob points out "[Do not cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495)"